# Contant refreshing the entire page, Timer and label

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, page-refresh, ticker

I'm doing a timer which shows the current time right now. 
However, the entire page is constantly refreshing along with the label

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
  this.lbl_time.Text = dateTime.ToString();}
```

Comment: So what's your problem?!

Comment: You can use javascript to updated label with current time instead of sending call to server to get the time. It will show client time but to show server time you can initialize server time and later use javascipt to update time.

Comment: I'd like to display the current time on the website, but the page keeps refreshing